# Increase value after 5 seconds on page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I need to increase a value in the database after the user spends 5 seconds on the page.

I have this so far (without any delay) at the top of the php file:

```
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('UPDATE table SET column = column + 1 WHERE title = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $title);
$stmt->execute();
```

How would I run that query after the user spends 5 seconds on the page?

Comment: by sending ajax request after 5 seconds...or using hidden iframe and count seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using -

`AJAX` and `setTimeout`

```
function updateDb() {
     $.ajax({
        url : 'update.php'
    });

    setTimeout(updateDb, 5000);
}

updateDb();
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without loading from another file?

Comment: You have to send request to server in order to perform any database update. Now its your choice to `reload` whole page or just send an `ajax` request.

Comment: no, the client (javascript) can't access the database, only the server (php) so you have to open a php page for it to update, php code doesn't run after the page is already loaded, only when you load it

Comment: I've tried your code, but when I wait 5 seconds, it doesn't run the query and everything seems right. :/

Comment: A little debugging will help you.

Comment: You probably don't have jQuery, or you don't set the timeout again, check my answer, you don't need jQuery with mine and I do set the timeout again.

Comment: Got it working. Just forgot to add some data I was missing. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Make a new php (let's say it's named dbupdate.php) file with only:

```
<?php $stmt = $cxn->prepare('UPDATE table SET column = column + 1 WHERE title = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $title);
$stmt->execute(); ?>
```

And then add this to your original file:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","dbupdate.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
setTimeout(loadXMLDoc,5000);
}
setTimeout(loadXMLDoc,5000);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know where you declare the $title variable though. You also need to add that on the first file I mention.